# SQL Server : error validating the default for a XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to set the default value for a new column I just added. In properties I am trying to set '`Default Value or Binding'` to a simple XML along the lines of:

```
<root>
   <title>Welcome</title>
   <body>Thank you for your time.</body>
</root>
```

However, when I click away, I get an error:

> SQL error validating the default for column

I set this value in other numerical columns and it worked fine. What gives?

Comment: Show the SQL that creates the table. If you don't specify a value for a column it will use the default. I think the problem is there.

Comment: Agreed 100% with Marc. Stop using the designers and UIs and learn the syntax. You will be way, way, way better off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, but the visual designers in SQL Server Management Studio often don't quite work properly...

Just use a simple T-SQL statement to achieve the same thing:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableName
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_YourTable_YourXmlColumn
    DEFAULT '<root><title>Welcome</title><body>Thank you for your time.</body></root>' 
    FOR YourXmlColumn
```

and you're done!

(*You didn't specify your table and column names - so I just made up placeholders - do replace those with your **actual** table and column names! Also: for the default constraint, I'd always recommend specifying an explicit name - makes it easier to disable and/or drop the constraint later, if you ever need to; my default naming convention is shown - again: adapt to your needs / likes*)

Answer (score 1):

It is true that knowing what TSQL command to run is advantageous in many ways but just to add an answer for SQL Server Management Studio so it is not swept under "it doesn't quite work properly", the syntax is ('[xml here]').

```
('<root><title>Welcome</title><body>Thank you for your time.</body></root>')
```